# Unity3D Network Request flow

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I have a `Player` class, which stores player's information.

```
public class Player {
  private string player_id;

  public static void NewPlayer(string name) {
    Debug.Log("NewPlayer");
    Player p = new Player();
    p.player_id = "123";
    p.register();
  }

  private void register() {
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("mode", "register");
    form.AddField("player_id", this.player_id);
    NetworkManager nm = NetworkManager.instance;
    nm.OnFinish += HandleOnFinish;
    nm.Push (new NetworkManager.Request(NetworkManager.API_URL, HandleFinishNetwork, form));
    nm.Execute();
  }

  void HandleFinishNetwork(WWW www) {
    if(www.text == "OK") {
      Debug.Log("Registration OK");
      // *** what should I put here to return the Player object to the scene? ***
    } else {
      Debug.Log("Unexpected Data Returned: " + www.text);
    }
  }
}
```

where `NetworkManager` is a class that extends `MonoBehaviour` and `System.IDisposable`. When `NetworkManager` finishes network operation, it will call `OnFinish` event in `Player` class.

I have a Unity scene which has a GUI button that triggers `Player.NewPlayer("MyName")`. How can I return a `Player` object back to the Scene when Registration is OK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are going to do with the Player or how you are going to manipulate it, but a good general solution would be to use a delegate to execute when the Player is registered, like this:

```
public class Player {
  private string player_id;
  private Action<Player> onPlayerRegistered;

  public static void NewPlayer(string name, Action<Player> onPlayerRegistered) {
    Debug.Log("NewPlayer");
    Player p = new Player();
    p.player_id = "123";
    p.onPlayerRegistered = onPlayerRegistered;
    p.register();
  }

  // ...

  void HandleFinishNetwork(WWW www) {
    if(www.text == "OK") {
      Debug.Log("Registration OK");
      onPlayerRegistered(this);
    } else {
      Debug.Log("Unexpected Data Returned: " + www.text);
    }
  }
}
```

And in the class that will be creating the player, you'd do something like this:

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Start() {
        Player.NewPlayer("Steve Woz", StartTheGame);
    }

    private void StartTheGame(Player player) {
        StopTheSpiningWheel();
        ReallyStart(player);
        Whatever();
    }
```

Or even:

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Start() {
        Player.NewPlayer("Steve Woz", (player) => { Debug.Log("My name is " + player.name); });
    }
```

So, the idea is to pass the method that needs the player to be executed when there's a player (that is, when it is registered). My exemple uses the convenient [Action class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this last piece of code uses a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that's generally a good idea to use if you have a simple enough code that you want to run.

Finally, take a look at [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx) that describes the Observer design pattern, for a complete and boring explanation.

Comment: Very detailed explanation. Thanks!